# ASP.NET MVC image from byte array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

currently I have a byte array representing my Image in my ViewModel. I display it with the following code:

```
<img src="@String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Image))" />
```

Now I don't want to have a Base64 String in my Source file, but rather a link to a image. Like:

```
<img src="Images/" + Model.Id"/>
```

which would return a Image.

How do I write such a method to return a Image link?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You could define a controller action that will serve the image:

```
public class ImagesController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        byte[] imageData = ... go get your image data from the id
        return File(imageData, "image/png"); // Might need to adjust the content type based on your actual image type
    }
}
```

and in your view simply point the `src` property of the `img` tag to this controller action:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("Index", "Images", new { id = Model.Id })" />
```

Comment: The generated file is temporary?

Comment: @notsoux, there's no file involved in here. The server is streaming data from the database directly to the client without creating any files. It's up to the client to decide what to do with this stream.

Comment: "It's up to the client to decide what to do with this stream." .. well said...:)

Answer (score 11):

One way is to add this to a new c# class or HtmlExtensionsclass

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString Image(this HtmlHelper html, byte[] image)
    {
        var img = String.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", Convert.ToBase64String(image));
        return new MvcHtmlString("<img src='" + img + "' />");
    }
}
```

then you can do this in any view

```
@Html.Image(Model.MyImageBytes)
```