# Specifying port number in img src return from controller action

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller returning a image (Code based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186062/can-an-asp-net-mvc-controller-return-an-image))

When I use that as a src on my  tag, I need to specify the port # as follows:

```
http://localhost:<Port #>/MyController/Image/MyImage
```

Is there a way I can avoid using the port #?

Comment: Just use `/MyController/Image/MyImage`. You don't need the full URL

Comment: Just look this solution [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165376/asp-net-mvc-image-from-byte-array)