# Create a temporary URL to an image

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a List of images in byte array format. I want to show these images on a page. This code works:

```
List<string> photoData = new List<string>();

foreach (var photoBytes in PhotoByteArrayList)
{
    var imageBase64Data = Convert.ToBase64String(photoBytes);
    var imageUrl = "data:image/JPEG;base64," + imageBase64Data;
    photoData.Add(imageUrl);
}

return View(photos);
```

I have a view that looks like this:

```
@model List<string>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>All Images</h2>

@foreach (var item in @Model)
{
    <img src="@item" />
}
```

This works. However: this solution means that the page's HTML contains giant strings of image data. This causes the whole page to take ages to load. What I would rather do is:

1. Store the image byte array in some sort of temporary storage in the controller.
2. Generate a temporary URL for this image.
3. Pass a List of URL strings to my page.
4. Display the images using these temporary URLs.

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: why the URL needs to be temporary?

Comment: Because the images are stored in a database, and not in the file system (sadly, this can't be changed).

Comment: That isn't relevant. Browser doesn't care about where the image is stored. The url might be hostname/GetImage?id=1234 where 1234 is the unique image id. Every time a browser asks  for an image with id 1234 it will get the same image. No difference with an url like hostname/images/1234.png

Comment: As a performance suggestion, I can additionally suggest you have dynamic compression enabled on your IIS server

Comment: Could be a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165376/asp-net-mvc-image-from-byte-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an action method which returns you the image. Use the `File` method to return the image.

```
public ActionResult MyImg(int id)
{
   byte[] bytes =GetByteArrayOfYourImageFromSomeWhere(id);
   return File(bytes, "image/jpg");
}
```

Assumin `GetByteArrayOfYourImageFromSomeWhere()` method accepts a unique Id related to your image and return the byte array version of the image stored in your table.

And in your views, you can can call this action method as the image source

```
<img src="@Url.Action("MyImg","YourControllerName",new { id=250 })" alt="hi" />
```

Replace `250` with a valid unique numeric id related to your image.